# Unable to deploy contract using truffle-contract?

Tags: web3js, truffle-contract

I'm trying to deploy a new contract via `truffle-contract` but for some reason it keeps giving me a `Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""`

```
import Web3 from 'web3'
import contract from 'truffle-contract'

import MyContract from '../build/MyContract.json'

const Contract = contract(MyContract)
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/...'))

MyContract.defaults({
  from: 0x...,
  gasPrice: '21000000000',
  gas: 4712388
})

MyContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider)

async function deployContract() {
  let contractInstance = await MyContract.new()
  console.log(contractInstance.address)
}


deployContract()
```

Comment: The deployment transaction needs signing. Infura is not going to do that for you. That's why you should use an alternative like [truffle-hdwallet-provider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider) instead of the plain HttpProvider. This provider will sign the transaction for you, before sending it off to Infura.

Comment: @Henk am I not signing it using the `MyContract.defaults` and specifying the `from` field?

Comment: No, because you're not providing a private key or a mnemonic anywhere to sign with

Comment: @Henk I realized I am signing it, in my `truffle.js` file. I have my private keys and providers defined there. Any reason I'm still getting this error?

Comment: Yes, you might be creating providers there, but you're not using them in the code you posted. You are creating a new Web3 instance which has no access to your private keys. Use the Web3 instance truffle injects for you. Try removing this line: `const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/...'))`

Comment: I also have the following two lines in the code that I didn't provide `const applicationAccount = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount('privateKey')`
and 
`web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(applicationAccount)`